# OrderBy filter angular with nested objects throws error

Tags: angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
[{
    "type": "adserver",
    "stats": {
        "10021": 48082,
        "10023": 1741
    }
}, {
    "type": "adserver",
    "stats": {
        "10021": 12312,
        "10023": 23
    }
}, {
    "type": "adserver",
    "stats": {
        "10021": 53423,
        "10023": 54
    }
}, {
    "type": "adserver",
    "stats": {
        "10021": 12345,
        "10023": 12
    }
}]
```

I'm trying to use:

`ng-repeat = "array | orderBy:'stats.10021'"`

and it throws this error:

> Syntax Error: Token '.10021' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the
>   expression [stats.10021] starting at [.10021].

Comment: <div ng-repeat="single in array | orderBy:'stats.10021'">
     <businesscard>{{single.type}} {{single.stats}}</businesscard>
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to the fact that you are trying to access an object property which keys are numbers. You have to access the properties with square parameters.

You cannot access object properties with dot notation which keys are numbers!

Try this instead:

```
ng-repeat = "(key, value) in array | orderBy:'stats['10021']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object property names can not start with a number so you can only access them as string name using `[]` notation

Try

```
orderBy:stats['10021']
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mwjr/538/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="single in array | orderBy:'stats.10021'">
     <businesscard>{{single.type}} {{single.stats}}</businesscard>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [{"type":"adserver","stats":{"10021":48082,"10023":1741}}, {"type":"adserver","stats":{"10021":12312,"10023":23}}, {"type":"adserver","stats":{"10021":53423,"10023":54}}, {"type":"adserver","stats":{"10021":12345,"10023":12}}]
});
```

> output

adserver {"10021":12312,"10023":23}

adserver {"10021":12345,"10023":12}

adserver {"10021":48082,"10023":1741}

adserver {"10021":53423,"10023":54}